# Integral value is not coming properly in Python

Tags: python, continuous-integration, normal-distribution, sage

I take a Normal distribution with mean 8704 & standard deviation 1. So the integration of density function over [-infinity, infinity] should be 1. But I am getting much less. Am I missing anything? I have written this in Sagemath.

```
from mpmath import *
import time
mp.dps = 200
mp.pretty = True

mu0=8704 
sigma0=1

F1 = lambda x: 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma0)*e^(-(x-mu0)^2/(2*sigma0^2))
J=quad(F1, [-inf,inf])
print J
```

Comment: I assume the `^` is meant to be a "power of" symbol. I think even with `mpmath` you need to be using the Python standard power symbol of `**`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Thanks. But I have written in Sagemath.

Comment: If I replace the `^` with `**`, and run everything as shown in your code...I get `5.3651448...`. If I run with the `^`, I get a division by 0 error. Neither is closer to 1 :D But the way you have presented the formula in the python code appears correct, at least to the formula I found at http://tloux.faculty.pstat.ucsb.edu/tip-sheets/integrating-densities. NOTE: When you run this code, `x will = 1`

Comment: "But I have written in Sagemath". Ah. You might want to add that in the OP, and in the tags, if you can.

Comment: Apart from the bad sintax you have to revise (there is more than a couple parenthesis off I believe), I've tried the same thing, and I figured it's some sort of overflow/underflow error, because when you keep mu0 small enough, say less than 50, then it works fine, but the more you increase it the more it's going to be off. I'm still trying to work on it, but unsuccessfully so far.

Comment: Agreed, the latter is really interesting.  Replacing `e^` with `exp()` from mpmath doesn't seem to help significantly, either. I think that the real problem is your `dps`, but I don't know how well it will support a higher precision for such huge standard deviations.

Comment: You may also want to write the author of mpmath directly if you can't find more documentation at http://mpmath.org/doc/1.1.0/index.html or help at ask.sagemath.org.